# Error 400, 1004 in VBA-Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use a macro written and shared as the [supplemental material](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/suppl/10.1021/la990209u) of a [scientific paper](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/la990209u) published in 1999.
I believe the macro has been written under Excel 1997 environment.
Unfortunately, I have very poor knowledge of VBA-Excel, and as far as I could understand, there might be a problem regarding the call of method .Select or .Range for the ActiveSheet, due to/along with an incompatibility between Excel 1997 and nowadays Excel 2010 (the one I am using).

It seems that VBA-Excel environment has quite a powerful debugging interface, although my poor knowledge of this language doesn't provide sufficient understanding to debug by myself.

My question is: can you try to run the macro, face the bug and corresponding error message, and fix (or help me fixing) the code?

Thank you very much.

Here is the macro:

```
'
'PSD MACRO
'Macro 7/24/97 by Wayne Lukens
'
'New Sheet Column assignments
'1 - Pressure, Pr = p/p0
'2 - Gas Volume adsorbed, Vg
'3 - Volume adsorbed as liquid, V1
'4 - Critical thickness, Tcr
'5 - Critical Radius, Rcr
'6 - Critical Pressure for Rave, Pave
'7 - Critical Thickness for Rave, Pave
'8 - Average Pore Radius, Rave
'9 - Average Pore Diameter, Dave
'10 - Volume of the Kelvin cores, Vc
'11 - Cross Sectional Area
'12 - Number of pores at a given pressure, Lp
'13 - Total volume of pores of radius Rave, Vc
'14 - Volume of gas desorbed in a step, Vd
'15 - Dave again
'
Sub PSD()
'
'Set up variables
'

    Dim Pr(100), Rcr(100), V1(100), Tcr(100), Vd(100), Csa(100), Vc(100), Pave(100)
    Dim PoreV(100), Lp(100), Tave(100), Rc(100), Rave(100), Te(100, 100)
    Dim Te1 As String
    Dim C(10), T, f, df, dx, Tlast As Double
    PageTitle = "Adsorp in "
    MeniscusTitle = "Hemisperical Meniscus"
    Pi = 3.14159
    a = 5 * (3.54 ^ 3)
' factoroot = 4.05*Log(10)
    R = 0.8314
    T = 77.2
    RT = R * T
    Gamma = 8.72
    Vm = 34.68
    factoroot = 2 * Gamma * Vm / (R * T)
    PoreType = ""
' Welcome = MsgBox("Welcome to Broekhoff-de-Boer analysis with a Frenkel-Halsey-Hill isotherm.",vbOKOnly)
    On Error Resume Next
        Set dData = Application.InputBox("Please select the cells which contain your isotherm data. The data must " & "contain p/p0 in column 1 and the volume of gas adsorbed (as gas) in column 2.", "Select Isotherm Data", Type:=8)
            If Err <> 0 Then
                On Error GoTo 0
                Exit Sub
            End If
        On Error GoTo 0

'
'Get information from the user to determine pore model and meniscus shape
'

    Do Until PoreType = "sphere" Or PoreType = "s" Or PoreType = "cylinder" Or PoreType = "c" Or PoreType = False
        PoreType = Application.InputBox("Which pore model are you using, cylinder or sphere (c or s)?", "Pore Model")
        Loop
        If PoreType = False Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        answer1 = MsgBox("Is this an adsorption isotherm?", vbYesNo)
        Answer2 = MsgBox("Does the isotherm display hysteresis?", vbYesNo)
        alpha = InputBox("What is the value of the FHH parameter, alpha? (Default = 5*3.54^3)", "Enter alpha", a)
        If answer1 = vbNo Then
            PoreType = "c"
            PageTitle = "Desorp from"
        End If
        If PoreType = "sphere" Or PoreType = "s" Then
            ModelSheet = "Spheres"
            PoreType = "s"
            factory = factoroot
            PoreTitle = "Spherical Pores"
        Else
            ModelSheet = "Cylinders"
            PoreType = "c"
            factory = factoroot / 2
            PoreTitle = "Cylindrical Pores"
        End If
        If Answer2 = vbNo Then ModelSheet = ModelSheet & "no Hy"
        If alpha = "" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If answer1 = vbYes Then
            celltitle = "Adsorption in " & ModelSheet
        Else
            celltitle = "Desorption from " & ModelSheet
        End If

        ModelSheet = PageTitle & ModelSheet


'
'Copy selected data to new sheets.
'

    ActiveSheet.Activate
    dData.Select
    Selection.Copy
    'Application.Workbook.Add
    ActiveSheet.Activate
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.Name = ModelSheet
    Sheets(ModelSheet).Activate
    Selection.Sort Key1:=ActiveCell, Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBotom
    '
    'Convert gas volumes into liquid volumes
    '

        iRows = Selection.Rows.Count
        Cells(1, 3).Formula = " =B1*0.0015468"
        Cells(1, 3).Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(iRows, 3)), Type:=x1FillDefault
'
'Fill array
'
    For I = 1 To iRows
        Pr(I) = Cells(I, 1)
        V1(I) = Cells(I, 3)
    Next I

    If answer1 = vbNo Or Answer2 = vbNo Then

'
'Calculate Critical Radius and Pore Diameter at each Pressure for a Desorption Branch
'
    If answer1 = vbNo Then
        BranchTitle = "Desorption from"
    Else
        BranchTitle = "Adsorption w/o Hysteresis" & Chr(13) & "in"
    End If
    fa = factoroot / 2
    For I = 1 To iRows

        Inp = -Log(Pr(I))
        THigh = 5 * (alpha / Inp) ^ (1 / 3)
        TLow = 0.5 * (alpha / Inp) ^ (1 / 3)
        T = 3 * (alpha / Inp) ^ (1 / 3)
        C(1) = alpha * alpha / Inp
        C(2) = 0#
        C(3) = -2 * alpha * fa / Inp
        C(4) = -2 * alpha
        C(5) = 0#
        C(6) = fa
        C(7) = Inp
        For K = 1 To 20
            f = C(1) + T * T * (C(3) + T * (C(4) + T * T * (C(6) + T * C(7))))
            df = T * (2 * C(3) + T * (3 * C(4) + T * T * (5 * C(6) + T * 6 * C(7))))
            dx = f / df
            If dx > 0 Then
                THigh = T
            End If
            If dx < 0 Then
                TLow = T
            End If
            T = T - dx
            If (Abs(dx) < 0.00000000000001) Then Exit For
            If T > THigh Then
                T = (THigh + Tlast) / 2
            End If
            If T < TLow Then
                T = (TLow + Tlast / 2)
            End If
            Tlast = T
         Next K
         Tcr(I) = T
         Cells(I, 4) = T
         Rcr(I) = Tcr(I) + fa / (Inp - alpha / (Tcr(I) ^ 3))
    Next I
    Else
'
'Calculate Critical Radius and Pore Diameter at each pressure for an Adsorption Branch
'
    If PoreType = "c" Then MeniscusTitle = "Cylindrical Meniscus"
    BranchTitle = "Adsorption in"
    For I = 1 To iRows
        logprel = Log(Pr(I))
        q = -((alpha * factory / 3) ^ 0.5) / logprel
        R = alpha / (2 * logprel)
        If R ^ 2 < q ^ 3 Then
            x = R / Sqr(q ^ 3)
            theta = Atn(-x / Sqr(-x * x + 1)) + 1.5708
            root2 = -2 * Sqr(q) * Cos((theta + 2 * 3.14159) / 3)
            Tcr(I) = root2
        Else
            a = -Sgn(R) * (Abs(R) + Sqr(R ^ 2 - q ^ 3)) ^ (1 / 3)
            b = q / a
            Tcr(I) = a + b
        End If
        Rcr(I) = Tcr(I) + factory / (-logprel - alpha / Tcr(I) ^ 3)
     Next I
   End If

'
'Calculate the average pore radius for this desorption step
'

    For I = 1 To iRows - 1
        Rave(I) = (Rcr(I) + Rcr(I + 1)) * Rcr(I) * Rcr(I + 1) / (Rcr(I) ^ 2 + Rcr(I + 1) ^ 2)
'
'Calculate the critical thickness and pressure for each Rave since Rave is known
'

        a = Sqr(factory)
        b = Sqr(3 * alpha)
        d = -Rave(I) * b
        q = -0.5 * (b + Sgn(b) * Sqr(b ^ 2 - 4 * a * d))
        Tave(I) = d / q
        Pave(I) = Exp(-(factory / (Rave(I) - Tave(I)) + alpha / Tave(I) ^ 3))
    Next I
'
'Calculate Equilibrium Thickness at every pressure for each pore radius using the Newton-Raphson method
'

    C(2) = alpha
    C(3) = 0#
    For I = 2 To iRows
        Rcrit = Rave(I - 1)
        C(1) = -alpha * Rcrit
        T = Tcr(I)
        For J = I + 1 To iRows + 1
            Prel = Pr(J - 1)
            Plog = -Log(Prel)
            C(5) = -Plog
            C(4) = Rcrit * Plog - factory
            For K = 1 To 20
                f = C(1) + T * (C(2) + T ^ 2 * (C(4) + T * C(5)))
                df = C(2) + T * (T * (3 * C(4) + T * 4 * C(5)))
                dx = f / df
                T = T - dx
                If (Abs(dx) < 0.0000000001) Then Exit For
             Next K
             Te(J - 1, I - 1) = T
         Next J
    Next I
'
'Do the iterative part of the analysis
'

    For I = 1 To iRows - 1
'
'Calculate volume change for all previously opened pores
'
    Vd(I) = 0#
    If I = 1 Then
        Vd(I) = 0#
    Else
        For J = 1 To I - 1
'
'Calculate the total volume desorbed from the open pores during this interval
'
        If PoreType = "s" Then
            Vd(I) = Vd(I) + 1E-24 * (4 / 3) * Pi * ((Rave(J) - Te(I + 1, J)) ^ 3 - (Rave(J) - Te(I, J)) ^ 3) * Lp(J)
            'Note : In this case, Lp(J) is the number of spherical pores
        Else
            If PoreType = "c" Then
                Vd(I) = Vd(I) + 1E-16 * Pi * ((Rave(J) - Te(I + 1, J)) ^ 2 - (Rave(J) - Te(I, J)) ^ 2) * Lp(J)
                'Note : in this case, Lp(J) is the length of the cylindrical pore in cm.
                Else
                    sorry = MsgBox("error at Vd(I) stae", vbOKOnly)
                    Exit Sub
                End If
        End If
        Next J
    End If
'
'Determine what's going on
'
    If Vd(I) >= (V1(I) - V1(I + 1)) Then
'
'The volume desorbed is less than the volume expected from desorption from opened pores, set the volume of the new pores to zero
'
'
        Lp(I) = 0#
        Vc(I) = 0#
        Csa(I) = 0#
    Else
'
'The volume desorbed is greater thant the volume expected, so the new pores must have opened
'
        Vc(I) = V1(I) - V1(I + 1) + Vd(I)

'
'Calculate the volume of the newly opened pores in cm3 at the end of the interval
'

        If PoreType = "s" Then
            Csa(I) = 4E-24 * (Pi / 3) * (Rave(I) - Te(I + 1, I)) ^ 3
        Else
            If PoreType = "c" Then
            Csa(I) = Pi * 1E-16 * (Rave(I) - Te(I + 1, I)) ^ 2
            Else
                sorry = MsgBox("error at Csa calculation", vbOKOnly)
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
'
'Calculate the number of pores
'
        Lp(I) = Vc(I) / Csa(I)
   End If
'
'Write values of important numbers to the worksheet"
'
        If PoreType = "s" Then
            PoreV(I) = 4E-24 * (Pi / 3) * Lp(I) * Rave(I) ^ 3
        Else
            If PoreType = "c" Then
            PoreV(I) = 1E-16 * Lp(I) * Pi * Rave(I) ^ 2

        Else
            sorry = MsgBox("error at PoreV calculation", vbOKOnly)
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
   Next I
'
'Do calculations for Incremental Pore Volumee
'
    Bigpoint = 0
    BigPointNumber = 1
    CumSA = 0
    CumPV = 0
    For J = 1 To iRows - 1
        Cells(J, 4) = Tcr(J)
        Cells(J, 5) = Rcr(J)
        Cells(J, 6) = Pave(J)
        Cells(J, 7) = Tave(J)
        Cells(J, 8) = Rave(J)
        Cells(J, 9) = Rave(J) * 2
        Cells(J, 10) = Vc(J)
        Cells(J, 11) = Csa(J)
        Cells(J, 12) = Lp(J)
        Cells(J, 13) = PoreV(J)
        Cells(J, 14) = Vd(J)
        Cells(J, 15) = Rave(J) * 2
        Cells(J, 16) = PoreV(J)
        If Rave(J) < 10 Then Exit For
        If Cells(J, 16) > Bigpoint Then
            BigPointNumber = J
            Bigpoint = Cells(J, 16)
        End If
'
'Calculate Surface Area in m2/g
'
    If PoreType = "s" Then
        Cells(J, 17) = 4E-20 * Pi * Lp(J) * Rave(J) ^ 2
    Else
        If PoreType = "c" Then
            Cells(J, 17) = 0.000000000002 * Pi * Lp(J) * Rave(J)
        Else
            sorry = MsgBox("Error at cumulative surface area calculation", vbOKOnly)
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    CumSA = CumSA + Cells(J, 17)
    CumPV = CumPV + PoreV(J)
    Cells(J, 18) = CumSA
    Cells(J, 19) = CumPV
    Next J
'
'Give Cells Headings
'
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Insert
    Cells(1, 1) = "Rel pres"
    Cells(1, 2) = "Vol as gas"
    Cells(1, 3) = "vol as liq"
    Cells(1, 4) = "Crit thick"
    Cells(1, 5) = "Crit radius"
    Cells(1, 6) = "Avg pres"
    Cells(1, 7) = "Avg thick"
    Cells(1, 8) = "Avg radius"
    Cells(1, 9) = "Avg diam"
    Cells(1, 10) = "Vol cores"
    Cells(1, 11) = "X sect area"
    Cells(1, 12) = "Pore length"
    Cells(1, 13) = celltitle
    Cells(1, 14) = "Vol desorp"
    Cells(1, 15) = "Avg diam"
    Cells(1, 16) = celltitle
    Cells(1, 17) = "Surf area"
    Cells(1, 18) = "Cumul SA"
    Cells(1, 19) = "Cumul PoreV"
    SurfaceArea = Fix(CumSA + 0.5)
    PoreVolume = Fix(100 * CumPV + 0.5) / 100

'
'Create a chart
'
    Columns("O:O").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
    Charts.Add
    ActiveChart.ChartWizard Source:=Sheets(ModelSheet).Range("$O:$P"), Gallery:=xlXYScatter, Format:=2, PlotBy:=xlColumns, CategoryLabels:=1, SeriesLabels:=1, HasLegend:=2, Title:="Plot for" & celltitle, CategoryTitle:="Pore Diameter in Angstroms", ValueTitle:="Pore Volume in cc per gram", ExtraTitle:=""
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    Nombre = ModelSheet & "Plot"
    ActiveSheet.Name = Nombre
End Sub
```

One can try the macro with the following set of data to embed in the sheet:

```
0.0106908   103.046
0.031249    120.144
0.0515578   129.808
0.0772499   138.616
0.100304    144.98
0.120399    149.797
0.140559    154.187
0.160819    158.255
0.18104 162.065
0.20132 165.698
0.24889 173.67
0.278214    178.398
0.303499    182.434
0.350487    189.809
0.375365    193.778
0.400622    197.828
0.425556    201.949
0.450624    206.146
0.475636    210.459
0.50072 214.991
0.525794    219.652
0.550631    224.562
0.575897    229.666
0.600643    235.066
0.625847    240.934
0.650973    247.074
0.675899    253.657
0.701025    260.816
0.725913    268.534
0.75098 277.212
0.776003    287.031
0.801318    298.016
0.813639    304.484
0.826658    311.591
0.838517    318.99
0.851442    327.799
0.863629    337.611
0.876573    349.305
0.888307    362.915
0.900328    383.552
0.911067    419.354
0.92187 475.714
0.952079    631.959
0.97104 817.134
0.979005    1038.01
0.984323    1250.95
0.99039 1436.81
```

Thanks again.

Comment: The only error Excel returns is "400".

Comment: Can you people please post a comment along with the negative note you append to my question?

I am sorry, but I have troubles facing the idea of having to learn VBA-Excel to solve the issue presented here. I do not see any intellectual benefit from learning such a language, given the use I would have out of it, in general. Here, I am asking for some help for a problem which I am sure is super easy to solve for someone who knows VBA-Excel.
I suppose I should rewrite the code in Python or Fortran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an updated version of the code. I've done the following:

- Declared and sorted all variables
- Given the code a good structure (tab-wise)
- Made the code run in background (speeded up code from 10s to >1s)
- The code begins with removing old data (generated charts and sheets)

  ```
  Option Explicit

  ' Books & Sheets
  Dim Wb1 As Workbook
  Dim Sh1 As Worksheet, Sh2 As Worksheet

  ' Doubles: One letter
  Dim A As Double, B As Double, D As Double, F As Double, J As Double, K As Double
  Dim R As Double, Q As Double, T As Double, X As Double

  ' Doubles: Two letters
  Dim dF As Double, dX As Double, fA As Double, Vm As Double, Rt As Double, Pi As Double

  ' Doubles: Three or more letters
  Dim Alpha As Double, BigPoint As Double, BigPointNumber As Double, CumSA As Double, CumPV As Double
  Dim Factory As Double, Gamma As Double, Inp As Double, LogpRel As Double, pLog As Double
  Dim PoreVolume As Double, pRel As Double, rCrit As Double, Root2 As Double, SurfaceArea As Double
  Dim Theta As Double, tHigh As Double, tLast As Double, tLow As Double

  ' Doubles: Arrays
  Dim C(10) As Double, Csa(100) As Double, Lp(100) As Double, Pave(100) As Double, PoreV(100) As Double
  Dim Pr(100) As Double, Rave(100) As Double, Rc(100) As Double, Rcr(100) As Double, Tave(100) As Double
  Dim Tcr(100) As Double, Te(100, 100) As Double, V1(100) As Double, Vc(100) As Double, Vd(100) As Double

  ' Longs
  Dim i&, iRows&

  ' Strings ($)
  Dim BranchTitle$, CellTitle$, FactoRoot$, MeniscusTitle$, ModelSheet$
  Dim PageTitle$, PoreTitle$, PoreType$, Spheres$, Te1$

  ' Booleans (True or False)
  Dim Answer1 As Boolean, Answer2 As Boolean

  ' Range
  Dim dData As Range

  ' PSD MACRO
  ' Macro 7/24/97 by Wayne Lukens
  '
  ' New Sheet Column assignments
  ' 1 - Pressure, Pr = p/p0
  ' 2 - Gas Volume adsorbed, Vg
  ' 3 - Volume adsorbed as liquid, V1
  ' 4 - Critical thickness, Tcr
  ' 5 - Critical Radius, Rcr
  ' 6 - Critical Pressure for Rave, Pave
  ' 7 - Critical Thickness for Rave, Pave
  ' 8 - Average Pore Radius, Rave
  ' 9 - Average Pore Diameter, Dave
  ' 10 - Volume of the Kelvin cores, Vc
  ' 11 - Cross Sectional Area
  ' 12 - Number of pores at a given pressure, Lp
  ' 13 - Total volume of pores of radius Rave, Vc
  ' 14 - Volume of gas desorbed in a step, Vd
  ' 15 - Dave again

  Sub PSD()

      ' Declare books and sheets
      Set Wb1 = ThisWorkbook
      Set Sh1 = Wb1.Sheets("Data")

      ' Delete old sheets if existing (graph and database)
      Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
          On Error Resume Next
              Sheets("Adsorp in Cylinders").Delete
              Sheets("Adsorp in Spheres").Delete
              Sheets("Adsorp in CylindersPlot").Delete
              Sheets("Adsorp in SpheresPlot").Delete
              Sheets("CylindersPlot").Delete
              Sheets("SpheresPlot").Delete
          On Error GoTo 0
      Application.DisplayAlerts = True

      ' Set up variables
      PageTitle = "Adsorp in "
      MeniscusTitle = "Hemisperical Meniscus"
      Pi = WorksheetFunction.Pi
      A = 5 * (3.54 ^ 3)
      ' factoroot = 4.05*Log(10)
      R = 0.8314
      T = 77.2
      Rt = R * T
      Gamma = 8.72
      Vm = 34.68
      FactoRoot = 2 * Gamma * Vm / (R * T)
      PoreType = ""

      ' Welcome = MsgBox("Welcome to Broekhoff-de-Boer analysis with a Frenkel-Halsey-Hill isotherm.",vbOKOnly)
      On Error Resume Next
          Set dData = Application.InputBox("Please select the cells which contain your isotherm data." & _
              "The data must " & "contain p/p0 in column 1 and the volume of gas adsorbed (as gas) in column 2.", _
              "Select Isotherm Data", Type:=8)
          If Err <> 0 Then
              On Error GoTo 0
              Exit Sub
          End If
      On Error GoTo 0

      ' Run everything in background (code runs faster)
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False

      Set dData = dData.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) ' Removes all cells but constants from selection

      ' Get information from the user to determine pore model and meniscus shape
      Do Until PoreType = "sphere" Or PoreType = "s" Or PoreType = "cylinder" Or PoreType = "c"
          PoreType = Application.InputBox("Which pore model are you using, cylinder or sphere (c or s)?", "Pore Model")
          If PoreType = "" Then Exit Sub
      Loop

      Answer1 = MsgBox("Is this an adsorption isotherm?", vbYesNo)
      Answer2 = MsgBox("Does the isotherm display hysteresis?", vbYesNo)
      Alpha = InputBox("What is the value of the FHH parameter, alpha? (Default = 5*3.54^3)", "Enter alpha", A)
      If Answer1 = False Then
          PoreType = "c"
          PageTitle = "Desorp from"
      End If
      If PoreType = "sphere" Or PoreType = "s" Then
          ModelSheet = "Spheres"
          PoreType = "s"
          Factory = FactoRoot
          PoreTitle = "Spherical Pores"
      Else
          ModelSheet = "Cylinders"
          PoreType = "c"
          Factory = FactoRoot / 2
          PoreTitle = "Cylindrical Pores"
      End If
      If Answer2 = False Then ModelSheet = ModelSheet & "no Hy"
      If Alpha = 0 Then Exit Sub

      If Answer1 = True Then
          CellTitle = "Adsorption in " & ModelSheet
      Else
          CellTitle = "Desorption from " & ModelSheet
      End If

      ' Copy selected data to new sheets
      dData.Copy

      Sheets.Add After:=Sh1
      ActiveSheet.Paste
      ActiveSheet.Name = PageTitle & ModelSheet
      Set Sh2 = Wb1.Sheets(PageTitle & ModelSheet)
      Selection.Sort Key1:=ActiveCell, Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

      ' Convert gas volumes into liquid volumes
      iRows = Selection.Rows.Count
      Cells(1, 3).Formula = "=B1*0.0015468"
      Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(iRows, 3)).Formula = Cells(1, 3).Formula


      ' Fill array
      For i = 1 To iRows
          Pr(i) = Cells(i, 1)
          V1(i) = Cells(i, 3)
      Next i

      If Answer1 = False Or Answer2 = False Then
          ' Calculate Critical Radius and Pore Diameter at each Pressure for a Desorption Branch
          If Answer1 = vbNo Then
              BranchTitle = "Desorption from"
          Else
              BranchTitle = "Adsorption w/o Hysteresis" & Chr(13) & "in"
          End If

          fA = FactoRoot / 2

          For i = 1 To iRows
              Inp = -Log(Pr(i))
              tHigh = 5 * (Alpha / Inp) ^ (1 / 3)
              tLow = 0.5 * (Alpha / Inp) ^ (1 / 3)
              T = 3 * (Alpha / Inp) ^ (1 / 3)
              C(1) = Alpha * Alpha / Inp
              C(2) = 0#
              C(3) = -2 * Alpha * fA / Inp
              C(4) = -2 * Alpha
              C(5) = 0#
              C(6) = fA
              C(7) = Inp
              For K = 1 To 20
                  F = C(1) + T * T * (C(3) + T * (C(4) + T * T * (C(6) + T * C(7))))
                  dF = T * (2 * C(3) + T * (3 * C(4) + T * T * (5 * C(6) + T * 6 * C(7))))
                  dX = F / dF
                  If dX > 0 Then tHigh = T
                  If dX < 0 Then tLow = T
                  T = T - dX
                  If (Abs(dX) < 0.00000000000001) Then Exit For
                  If T > tHigh Then T = (tHigh + tLast) / 2
                  If T < tLow Then T = (tLow + tLast / 2)
                  tLast = T
               Next K
               Tcr(i) = T
               Cells(i, 4) = T
               Rcr(i) = Tcr(i) + fA / (Inp - Alpha / (Tcr(i) ^ 3))
          Next i
      Else
          ' Calculate Critical Radius and Pore Diameter at each pressure for an Adsorption Branch
          If PoreType = "c" Then MeniscusTitle = "Cylindrical Meniscus"
          BranchTitle = "Adsorption in"
          For i = 1 To iRows
              LogpRel = Log(Pr(i))
              Q = -((Alpha * Factory / 3) ^ 0.5) / LogpRel
              R = Alpha / (2 * LogpRel)
              If R ^ 2 < Q ^ 3 Then
                  X = R / Sqr(Q ^ 3)
                  Theta = Atn(-X / Sqr(-X * X + 1)) + 1.5708
                  Root2 = -2 * Sqr(Q) * Cos((Theta + 2 * 3.14159) / 3)
                  Tcr(i) = Root2
              Else
                  A = -Sgn(R) * (Abs(R) + Sqr(R ^ 2 - Q ^ 3)) ^ (1 / 3)
                  B = Q / A
                  Tcr(i) = A + B
              End If
              Rcr(i) = Tcr(i) + Factory / (-LogpRel - Alpha / Tcr(i) ^ 3)
          Next i
      End If

      ' Calculate the average pore radius for this desorption step
      For i = 1 To iRows - 1
          Rave(i) = (Rcr(i) + Rcr(i + 1)) * Rcr(i) * Rcr(i + 1) / (Rcr(i) ^ 2 + Rcr(i + 1) ^ 2)
          ' Calculate the critical thickness and pressure for each Rave since Rave is known
          A = Sqr(Factory)
          B = Sqr(3 * Alpha)
          D = -Rave(i) * B
          Q = -0.5 * (B + Sgn(B) * Sqr(B ^ 2 - 4 * A * D))
          Tave(i) = D / Q
          Pave(i) = Exp(-(Factory / (Rave(i) - Tave(i)) + Alpha / Tave(i) ^ 3))
      Next i

      'Calculate Equilibrium Thickness at every pressure for each pore radius using the Newton-Raphson method
      C(2) = Alpha
      C(3) = 0#
      For i = 2 To iRows
          rCrit = Rave(i - 1)
          C(1) = -Alpha * rCrit
          T = Tcr(i)
          For J = i + 1 To iRows + 1
              pRel = Pr(J - 1)
              pLog = -Log(pRel)
              C(5) = -pLog
              C(4) = rCrit * pLog - Factory
              For K = 1 To 20
                  F = C(1) + T * (C(2) + T ^ 2 * (C(4) + T * C(5)))
                  dF = C(2) + T * (T * (3 * C(4) + T * 4 * C(5)))
                  dX = F / dF
                  T = T - dX
                  If (Abs(dX) < 0.0000000001) Then Exit For
               Next K
               Te(J - 1, i - 1) = T
           Next J
      Next i

      ' Do the iterative part of the analysis
      For i = 1 To iRows - 1
          ' Calculate volume change for all previously opened pores
          Vd(i) = 0#
          If i = 1 Then
              Vd(i) = 0#
          Else
              For J = 1 To i - 1
                  ' Calculate the total volume desorbed from the open pores during this interval
                  If PoreType = "s" Then
                      Vd(i) = Vd(i) + 1E-24 * (4 / 3) * Pi * ((Rave(J) - Te(i + 1, J)) ^ 3 - (Rave(J) - Te(i, J)) ^ 3) * Lp(J)
                      ' Note : In this case, Lp(J) is the number of spherical pores
                  Else
                      If PoreType = "c" Then
                          Vd(i) = Vd(i) + 1E-16 * Pi * ((Rave(J) - Te(i + 1, J)) ^ 2 - (Rave(J) - Te(i, J)) ^ 2) * Lp(J)
                          ' Note : in this case, Lp(J) is the length of the cylindrical pore in cm.
                      Else
                          MsgBox "Error at Vd(I) stae", vbOKOnly
                          Exit Sub
                      End If
                  End If
              Next J
          End If

          ' Determine what's going on
          If Vd(i) >= (V1(i) - V1(i + 1)) Then
              ' The volume desorbed is less than the volume expected from desorption from opened pores, set the volume of the new pores to zero
              Lp(i) = 0#
              Vc(i) = 0#
              Csa(i) = 0#
          Else
              ' The volume desorbed is greater thant the volume expected, so the new pores must have opened
              Vc(i) = V1(i) - V1(i + 1) + Vd(i)
              ' Calculate the volume of the newly opened pores in cm3 at the end of the interval
              If PoreType = "s" Then
                  Csa(i) = 4E-24 * (Pi / 3) * (Rave(i) - Te(i + 1, i)) ^ 3
              Else
                  If PoreType = "c" Then
                      Csa(i) = Pi * 1E-16 * (Rave(i) - Te(i + 1, i)) ^ 2
                  Else
                      MsgBox "Error at Csa calculation", vbOKOnly
                      Exit Sub
                  End If
              End If

              ' Calculate the number of pores
              Lp(i) = Vc(i) / Csa(i)
          End If

          ' Write values of important numbers to the worksheet
          If PoreType = "s" Then
              PoreV(i) = 4E-24 * (Pi / 3) * Lp(i) * Rave(i) ^ 3
          Else
              If PoreType = "c" Then
                  PoreV(i) = 1E-16 * Lp(i) * Pi * Rave(i) ^ 2
              Else
                  MsgBox "Error at PoreV calculation", vbOKOnly
                  Exit Sub
              End If
          End If
      Next i

      'Do calculations for Incremental Pore Volumee
      BigPoint = 0
      BigPointNumber = 1
      CumSA = 0
      CumPV = 0
      For J = 1 To iRows - 1
          Cells(J, 4) = Tcr(J)
          Cells(J, 5) = Rcr(J)
          Cells(J, 6) = Pave(J)
          Cells(J, 7) = Tave(J)
          Cells(J, 8) = Rave(J)
          Cells(J, 9) = Rave(J) * 2
          Cells(J, 10) = Vc(J)
          Cells(J, 11) = Csa(J)
          Cells(J, 12) = Lp(J)
          Cells(J, 13) = PoreV(J)
          Cells(J, 14) = Vd(J)
          Cells(J, 15) = Rave(J) * 2
          Cells(J, 16) = PoreV(J)
          If Rave(J) < 10 Then Exit For
          If Cells(J, 16) > BigPoint Then
              BigPointNumber = J
              BigPoint = Cells(J, 16)
          End If

          'Calculate Surface Area in m2/g
          If PoreType = "s" Then
              Cells(J, 17) = 4E-20 * Pi * Lp(J) * Rave(J) ^ 2
          Else
              If PoreType = "c" Then
                  Cells(J, 17) = 0.000000000002 * Pi * Lp(J) * Rave(J)
              Else
                  MsgBox "Error at cumulative surface area calculation", vbOKOnly
                  Exit Sub
              End If
          End If
          CumSA = CumSA + Cells(J, 17)
          CumPV = CumPV + PoreV(J)
          Cells(J, 18) = CumSA
          Cells(J, 19) = CumPV
      Next J

      'Give Cells Headings
      Rows(1).Insert
      Cells(1, 1) = "Rel pres"
      Cells(1, 2) = "Vol as gas"
      Cells(1, 3) = "vol as liq"
      Cells(1, 4) = "Crit thick"
      Cells(1, 5) = "Crit radius"
      Cells(1, 6) = "Avg pres"
      Cells(1, 7) = "Avg thick"
      Cells(1, 8) = "Avg radius"
      Cells(1, 9) = "Avg diam"
      Cells(1, 10) = "Vol cores"
      Cells(1, 11) = "X sect area"
      Cells(1, 12) = "Pore length"
      Cells(1, 13) = CellTitle
      Cells(1, 14) = "Vol desorp"
      Cells(1, 15) = "Avg diam"
      Cells(1, 16) = CellTitle
      Cells(1, 17) = "Surf area"
      Cells(1, 18) = "Cumul SA"
      Cells(1, 19) = "Cumul PoreV"
      SurfaceArea = Fix(CumSA + 0.5)
      PoreVolume = Fix(100 * CumPV + 0.5) / 100

      'Create a chart
      Columns("O:O").NumberFormat = "0"
      Range("A1").Select
      ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
      Charts.Add After:=Sh1
      ActiveChart.ChartWizard Source:=Sheets(PageTitle & ModelSheet).Range("$O:$P"), Gallery:=xlXYScatter, _
          Format:=2, PlotBy:=xlColumns, CategoryLabels:=1, SeriesLabels:=1, HasLegend:=2, _
          Title:="Plot for" & CellTitle, CategoryTitle:="Pore Diameter in Angstroms", _
          ValueTitle:="Pore Volume in cc per gram", ExtraTitle:=""
      ActiveSheet.Name = ModelSheet & "Plot"
      Calculate
      Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Thank you so very much for your time and help. I am grasping things little by little as I run through the code you wrote, together with the suggested corrections of Rory. Unfortunately, the macro doesn't work as it is here. It seems that 
`For i = 1 To iRows _ Pr(i) = Cells(i, 1) _ V1(i) = Cells(i, 3) _ Next i`
induces an error about indexing issue. I am trying to see what I can do at the moment. Hope to read you soon.

Comment: I believe I have managed to make your code work, TAKL.
It turns out that I need to select the input data for the first prompt by clicking selecting the exact data in the two columns (i.e. $A$1:$B$47) rather than the whole two columns (which writes as $A:$B). If you believe that you can find further improvements, I will be more than happy to test! 
But now the macro runs now and seems to compute well. My biochemist friend will be elated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would want to select a certain amount of data, instead of the entire data. But yes, I will implement this in the upcoming code. If selecting columns A:B it will of course only select the data in those columns. Like I said, I'll release the new code tomorrow during with my first cup of joe.

Comment: Thank you TAKL for all the corrections and improvements.

Comment: No problem, @Jelle. Please mark my answer as useful if you feel that it is so.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of simple issues:

```
    Cells(1, 3).Formula = " =B1*0.0015468"
```

needs to be:
        Cells(1, 3).Formula = "=B1*0.0015468"

without the space before the '=' sign.

Also,
`xlTopToBotom` is misspelled - it needs to be `xlTopToBottom`. Similarly, `x1FillDefault` needs to be `xlFillDefault` (XL at the start, not X1)

Comment: Thank you.
I suspect an issue with the line `iRows = Selection.Rows.Count` now.
Did you manage to run the macro? If so, with what version of Excel?

Comment: I ran it in 2010 without errors using your sample data.

Comment: Alright. Is it possible that there are complementary Excel functions or Macros that you would have and that I don't have loaded (I have never used Excel to program anything)?

Comment: Nope. However there were a number of options to choose during the code - you didn't say which ones so I just clicked at random. Do you still get the same error?

Comment: Yes I still get the error. Apparently the error triggers around `iRows = Selection.Rows.Count`, because if I remove everything from this line up to `Exit Sub`, no error triggers. But I am not sure about the location and origin of the error.